# Adding Specific Value to Nested Lists

Tags: python, list

I'm having a comprehension issue on a specific problem. I have a preexisting nested list, and I want to match and append one value from a different list to the end of each nested list. A quick example of what I've tried, but where I'm stuck:

```
 initial_values = [["First", 1], ["Second", 2], ["Third", 3], ["Fourth", 4]]
other_values = [1,2,3,4]

for sublist in initial_values:
    for i in other_values:
        sublist.append(i)


print initial_values
```

This returns `[['First', 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], ['Second', 2, 1, 2, 3, 4], ['Third', 3, 1, 2, 3, 4], ['Fourth', 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]]`

I want it it to ideally return `[['First', 1, 1], ['Second', 2, 2], ['Third', 3, 3], ['Fourth', 4, 4]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double for-loop takes each sublist in turn (the outer for-loop) and appends every element of `other_values` to it (the inner for-loop). What you want instead is to add each element of `other_values` to the corresponding sublist (i.e. the sublist at the same position/index). Therefore, what you need is only one for-loop:

```
initial_values = [["First", 1], ["Second", 2], ["Third", 3], ["Fourth", 4]]
other_values = [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(len(initial_values)):  # get all the valid indices of `initial_values`
    initial_values[i].append(other_values[i])
```

Here's are some simpler ways to do it:

```
for i,subl in enumerate(initial_values):
    subl.append(other_values[i]))
```

Or

```
for subl, val in zip(initial_values, other_values):
    subl.append(val)
```

Comment: the solution with `enumerate` seems to be the most efficient one. No need to bother `zip` for this and create a lot of temporary objects.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: in python3, zip doesn't create temp objects - it returns an iterator with pointers to the original objects

Comment: I know that, but the tuples inside still have to be created.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: it's still O(1) space, since it's an iterator instead of a full list. Technically `enumerate` and `zip` have the same space complexity, though the time complexity may be different due to memory caching

Comment: I was talking about memory allocation avoided by the use of `enumerate` of course.

Comment: Thanks for such an informative response! I went with the enumerate method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to match elements of the same index from different lists. From there on, you're a simple list concatenation away:

```
[a + [b] for a,b in zip(initial_values, other_values)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to go through both lists with a single iteration. You could achieve that using zip:

```
for sublist, i in zip(initial_values, other_values):
    sublist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use for loop you can try

```
initial_values = [["First", 1], ["Second", 2], ["Third", 3], ["Fourth", 4]]
other_values = [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(0,len(other_values)):
    initial_values[i].append(other_values[i])

print initial_values
```

output:
`[['First', 1, 1], ['Second', 2, 2], ['Third', 3, 3], ['Fourth', 4, 4]]`

Answer (score 0):

Built-in function [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will match first item in first list with first item in second list etc.

```
initial_values = [["First", 1], ["Second", 2], ["Third", 3], ["Fourth", 4]]
other_values = [1,2,3,4]

for initials, other in zip(initial_values, other_values):
    initials.append(other)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the alternative to achieve it using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) as:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x[0] + [x[1]], zip(initial_values, other_values))
[['First', 1, 1], ['Second', 2, 2], ['Third', 3, 3], ['Fourth', 4, 4]]
```